# Find models that have only one particular related model

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many, django-orm

Consider the following models:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=...)

class Size(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=...)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, through=ProductXSize,
        related_name='sizes', related_query_name='size')

class ProductXSize(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='productxsizes', related_query_name='productxsize')
    size = models.ForeignKey(Size, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='productxsizes', related_query_name='productxsize')
```

What I'd like to achieve is along the lines of:

```
for p in Product.objects.filter(sizes=[Size.object.get(...)]):
    ...
```

That is, find products that have one size, and a particular one at that.

Comment: So you need to get all Product that have only one particular size? 
P.S why don't you have size FK in your `Product` as ForeighKey? And do you need an additional size field in your `ProductXSize` model as you can get size through `product`.

Comment: @SergeyPugach I don't have FK in `Product` model, since relationship is many-to-many. And I don't understand why I need additional size field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to annotate the queryset with an aggregated value:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/aggregation/#filtering-on-annotations

```
Product.objects.annotate(size_cnt=Count('size'))\  # annotate
    .filter(size_cnt=1)\  # keep all that have only one size
    .filter(size=...).all()  # keep all with a certain size
```